# How is Thanos able to hold almost all of the Infinity Stones barehanded?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

So in the movie we see Thanos holding the space, soul and mind Stones in his bare hands.
So how is he able to handle such powerful artifacts which even Quill (son of a celestial) was not able to do ( without disintegrating)?

Is it because of the fact that he is an Eternal with the Deviant Syndrome? Does he have the same origin as Comics?

Comment: Quill is half celestial & half human. Thor might hold it in his hands but at that moment he wasn't holding it. His head was subjected to the power of the Power Infinity Stone by Thanos. There's a difference

Comment: I don't think that was the case. All he did was put it against his head. He didn't use it like the Battle on Titan.

Comment: It was lit up in the glove... Thanos was using it and pressing it directly into Thor's skull.

Comment: Even so, it Doesn't explain how he is holding the Stones in his hand?

Comment: Only Power Stone was shown to disintegrate someone. Thanos is one of most powerful beings in universe, it would be silly if he couldn't hold Stones he wants to collect...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**How is Thanos able to hold almost all of the Infinity Stones barehanded?**

No answer is given in movie itself but this is what The Collector said about stones :

> "These stones, it seems, **can only be brandished by beings of extraordinary strength**. These carriers can use the stone to mow down entire civilizations like wheat in a field. Once, for a moment, a group was able to share the energy amongst themselves, but even they were quickly destroyed by it." ― Collector [<sub>src</sub>](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Collector/Quote)

It was never said that nobody can touch Infinity Stones barehanded. And we have not seen many powerful people even trying. Ronan touched power stone briefly before placing it on his hammer too.

**Is it because of the fact that he is an Eternal with the Deviant Syndrome? Does he have the same origin as Comics?**

We don't know, we can make wild guess for now, we do know that his father's name is the same:

> "Welcome Thanos, son of Alars." ―The Stonekeeper

And then this is what director's said:

> We were considering showing [Thanos'] backstory, but ultimately felt it wasn't necessary for the movie. - [cinemablend](https://www.cinemablend.com/news/2398692/why-avengers-infinity-war-wont-show-thanos-backstory-according-to-the-russos)

And we almost got a tie-in novel called [Thanos: Titan Consumed](https://screenrant.com/thanos-mcu-backstory-novel/) but it became non-canon now:

> Hey all - thanks for all the shares on this. Unfortunately, despite being told the novel is canon, the information given to me was INCORRECT. I'm really sorry about this. Article being fixed asap. - [twitter](https://mobile.twitter.com/GermainLussier/status/985977826393210880)

Answer (score 3):

By the time we see Thanos in Infinity War, he is already in possession of the Power Stone.

The Power Stone grants "extraordinary strength," which is stated in Guardian of the Galaxy Vol. 1 as the requirement for possessing a stone.

When a stone is activated, it glows in the gauntlet. Every time he holds a stone in his hand, the Power Stone is glowing.  From this, it can be inferred that he is using the strength granted to him by the Power Stone to wield the others without being destroyed.

Answer (score 2):

Thanos is from Saturn's moon Titan, there are two species on this moon and they are known as Eternals and Deviants. Thanos is a hybrid of both. The Eternals have many powers stemming from their control over some "Cosmic Energy" given to them by the Celestials. The celestials are a group of ancient aliens known to be some of the oldest entities in the Marvel Universe. The Celestials are responsible for the creation of the Eternals and also sentient life on earth, in the Marvel Universe. They also created the Deviants, Deviants are a counter species to the Eternals. The Celestials gave each Deviant a special power, the idea was to create an individual power for each Deviant. With both the Eternal and Deviant genes Thanos is an extremely powerful being to begin with, but he also altered himself later in life with an extreme scientific prowess, to make himself even more powerful. These are all factors from the comics, but I'm sure most of this information is used to rationalize why he can hold the stones with his bare hand and why he can control the gauntlet so well in the movies.

Comment: Is there a proof that this is his origin in MCU? The version you're describing is definitely the one in Earth- 616 main continuity of Marvel Comics.

Comment: There is little to no information on Thanos in the MCU, I don't really think they are worried about explaining it in the movies since so much has been done in the comics. Thanos has been in the other movies but only as a small character. So as I said, this is info from the comic books, but it can be used to rationalize why he can hold the stones, so I don't think they are worried about explaining it any further in the movies. That is unless we get more information about Thanos in the next Avengers movie. @AbhishekMishra

Comment: In the MCU, Titan is a planet in it's own system and not a moon in ours. They have changed Thanos's background, but his ability to hold and control the stones still comes from his background as a Titan and being (as Banner so eloquently stated) 'the strongest being in the universe'. The original story included a more in-depth look at Thanos as a character, including information on what allows him to hold the stones, but that was scrapped in the interest of time. [Here's more information on the scrapped scene](https://screenrant.com/infinity-war-mcu-titans-thanos/)

Comment: I'm waiting for the Blu-ray release. The Directors confirmed about roughly 5-10 minutes of extended footage. That might explain things.